# Is $\mathbb R$ saturated?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Consider $\mathbb R$ as a model of the field theory. Is it true that it is saturated?

$\mathbb C$ is saturated, since it is a model of ACF; $\mathbb Q$ is not, since it is not $\omega$-universal: $\mathbb Q(\pi)$ is a model of $Th(\mathbb Q,+,\cdot,0,1)$, but one cannot immerge it elementary in $\mathbb Q$; right?

What about $\mathbb R$? Since now I tried to repeat the proof that $\mathbb C$ is saturated, but it didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, it is not saturated. If you need a hint, notice: the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$ is definable using multiplication.

Comment: Using the field operations, rather.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, is my statement on $\mathbb Q$ true?

Comment: That'll work if you can prove the claim "$\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ doesn't embed elementarily into $\mathbb{Q}$".

Comment: The type of $\pi$ over the empty set is not realized in $\mathbb Q$, right?

Comment: @realdonaldtrump Except that $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are not elementarily equivalent.

Comment: That's interesting. Is it something simple that changes in the theory when you add a transcendental?

Comment: @realdonaldtrump It's a theorem that any field $K$ elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$ (but not equal to it) has infinite transcendence degree over $\mathbb{Q}$. I don't know a proof that will fit in the comments, but a reference is Corollary 4.13 in "Model Theoretic Algebra" by Jensen and Lenzing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. First, note that $x \leq y$ is definable in $\mathbb{R}$ by the formula $\exists z\,(z^2 = y-x)$. Now the partial type $\{n\leq x\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ (over the empty set) is finitely satisfiable in $\mathbb{R}$ but not realized in $\mathbb{R}$.

For the case of $\mathbb{Q}$, the partial type $\{ax + b \neq 0\mid a,b\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{-ax + b\neq 0\mid a,b\in \mathbb{N}\}$ (over the empty set) is finitely satisfiable in $\mathbb{Q}$, but not realized in $\mathbb{Q}$.

As I noted in the comments, your proposed argument does not work, because $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is not elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$. But *any* elementary extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ must contain an element realizing the partial type above, and hence can't be embedded elementarily in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an elementary way to see that $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is not elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$. Note that by Lagrange's four square theorem, every element $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ or $-x$ is a sum of four squares, whereas this is not the case in $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ ; neither $\pi$ nor $-\pi$ are the sum of four squares in $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$.